# Enumerate solutions in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I wanted to enumerate solutions of a non-deterministic goal `nondet_goal` as pairs `(Index, Value)` where `Index` is the index of each value returned. I managed to do it using `nb_setval`, `nb_getval` like this:

```
nb_setval(g_idx, 0),
findnsols(3, (Idx, Val), (nondet_goal(Val), nb_getval(g_idx, Idx), Idx1 is Idx + 1, nb_setval(g_idx, Idx1)), Out).
```

A quick test case may look like this:

```
L = [a,b,c,d,e],
nb_setval(g_idx, 0),
findnsols(3, (Idx, It), (member(It, L), nb_getval(g_idx, Idx), Idx1 is Idx + 1, nb_setval(g_idx, Idx1)), Out).
```

Which produces the intended output:

```
Out = [(0, a),  (1, b),  (2, c)] ;
Out = [(3, d),  (4, e)].
```

I'm wondering whether there is *a better way* to get values and indices. Ideally, if it doesn't need to generate a complete list of all solutions. Any help appreciated.

Cheers,
  Jacek

Comment: Can you post a solution example? I mean an example of output

Comment: The classic way of doing this is by using findall/3 or similar predicates but this way you will generate a complete list of all solutions...

Comment: Just added the output for the example I gave.

Comment: @coder, could you elaborate a little more on "the classic way". How would you produce indices with `findall`?

Comment: `findall( (Index, Value), Goal(Index, Value,possibly other parameters), L).`This will store all pairs (Index, Value) that makes Goal succeed in L and you can get them one at a time by using member(Out, L). Of course your goal is I think findnsols but you need to post the code or anyway use it in the above format.

Comment: @coder, sorry but my `nondet_goal` cannot return `Index`... it would be too simple ;-)

Comment: OK I may misunderstood...

Answer (score 2):

I would 'encapsulate' your code, that's already working well - except for reentrancy. So, let's start choosing a name for this abstraction:

```
enumerate_indexed_solutions(G, S, L) :-
   nb_setval(g_idx, 0),
   findnsols(3, I-S, (
     G,
     nb_getval(g_idx, I), I1 is I + 1, nb_setval(g_idx, I1)
   ), L).
```

which yields:

```
?- enumerate_indexed_solutions(member(V,[a,b,c,d,e]),V,L).
L = [0-a, 1-b, 2-c] ;
L = [3-d, 4-e].
```

edit:

```
enumerate_indexed :- nb_setval(g_idx, 0).
enumerate_indexed(I) :-
  nb_getval(g_idx, I), I1 is I + 1, nb_setval(g_idx, I1).

enumerate_indexed_solutions(G, S, L) :-
  enumerate_indexed,
  findnsols(3, I-S, (G, enumerate_indexed(I)), L).
```

Comment: Thank you, nice. I was missing the fact that `G` and `S` may depend on each other and wasn't sure how to write the rule. Still, wondering whether there's a way to get rid of `nb_{s/g}etval`.

Comment: Of course... let's introduce just another little abstraction.

Comment: Hmm... but that's hiding rather than getting rid of the `nb_xxx` operations. Anyway, thank you for the suggestions.